# Cannot return const from render ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have this component. If I do console.log(insurance) it displays an insurance object, but if I try to do console.log(insurance.id) I get `cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class EditInsurances extends Component {
  render() {
    const { insurances } = this.props;
    // get from url-route ID
    const insuranceId = this.props.match.params.id;

    const insurance = insurances.find(insurance => insurance.id == insuranceId);

   console.log(insurance.id);  <-error here( but if i do just 'insurance' it works
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>{insurance.tip}</p>  <-- also error here obv.
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EditInsurances
```

console.log(insurance) :

```
{id: 4, user_id: 1, tip: "Rovinieta", date_exp: "1977-02-13", date_notif: "1992-07-25", …}


created_at: "2019-03-11 09:49:23"
date_exp: "1977-02-13"
date_notif: "1992-07-25"
id: 4
note: "Et rem ea quia enim id incidunt."
tip: "Rovinieta"
updated_at: "2019-03-11 09:49:23"
user_id: 1
__proto__: Object
```

What should I do to access the objects properties?

Comment: can you post where in your code you are trying to place your two `console.log`s?

Comment: above return `(code) console.log(insurance.id) return ... (code)`

Comment: i edited, so you can see

Comment: And `console.log(insurance)` on the same line *does* work? Really?

Comment: Is `insurance` always defined ? What's `console.log(insurance && insurance.id)` giving out ?

Comment: @haim770 yes... it's wierd

Comment: @Treycos it returns 4, which is the id of my insurance. But why is this working and simply `insurance.id` not?

Comment: Please don't use `insurances.filter(insurance => insurance.id == insuranceId).shift();` Just `insurances.find(ins => ins.id === insuranceId)`

Comment: @JuanMendes i tried that too, but didn't work, so i changed it to this. I will change it back once i figure out what is happening. Thanks!

Comment: @DariusBiro That doesn't change the behavior of your code, I'm just saying that is wasteful and hard to follow

Comment: Yeah, thanks, sorry. I changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the `insurances` array comes from an asynchronous data source, and when you first load your `EditInsurances` this data is still loading.

With that assumption in mind, when `EditInsurances` component is first rendered the `insurances` prop is either empty or null.

If you `console.log(insurance)` you will get an empty console output, followed by another console output with your object.

If you had `console.log(insurance.id)` on the first render it will error, same goes for `insurance.tip` because the data is not available yet.

You should either only render `<EditInsurances insurances={...} />` if insurances exist or make the `EditInsurances` component more resilient through prop-type validation and checking the data before assuming its correct.

Comment: Yup, I'm pretty sure the OP has a null value and just hasn't done enough debugging/console.logging

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... I'm sure that the insurance exists... Could you give a more exact explanation please?

Comment: He means on first render, the `insurances` prop probably doesn't have all the records loaded and they pop in on the next update. So, your `console.log(insurance)` will at some point yield the object but trying to access the id will cause an error if the filter/find doesn't return anything. Try adding this to your render and remove the console logs? `if (!insurance) return <p>Loading...</p>`

Comment: I have no ideea what this did... but it works... Probably i'm not experienced enough, and I don't understand all that is going on... Anyway, thank you so much

Comment: I assume your `insurances` data comes from an API or some promise, when your component loads that data hasn't returned yet, leaving your component to try render without the required data.

Comment: So if your list of insurances hasn't finished loading, the prop will still be passed to your `EditInsurances` and then there is nothing in that component to handle checking for that. Your component is expecting the items to be present on the first render, but they seem to actually finishing loading after this render. The prop is updated with the loaded data which triggers an update, at this point your `console.log(object)` will return the insurance. However, if you try to access anything from your insurance object prior to this, it will error.

Answer (score 0):

another possibility

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import EditInsurances from "./EditInsurances";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const insurances = {
    id: "4",
    user_id: " 1",
    tip: "Rovinieta",
    date_exp: "1977-02-13",
    date_notif: "1992-07-25"
  };
return (
   <div className="App">
      <EditInsurances insurances={insurances} />
   </div>
   );
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

EditInsurances.js

```
class EditInsurances extends Component {
  render() {
     const { insurances } = this.props;
     // get from url-route ID
     const insuranceId = insurances.id;
     const insurance = Object.keys(insurances).map((item, indx) => {
         if (item[indx].id == insuranceId) {
            return item;
          }
     });

     return (
        <div>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>{insurances.tip}</p>
        </div>
     );
  }
}

 export default EditInsurances;
```

[codesandbox exaple](https://codesandbox.io/s/zm9x1m4jp)